# How to interrupt an Selenium thread with Java

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I'm trying to set a page refresh time out for my selenium test.
What I am trying to do is:

If selenium can not findElement on the page in a number seconds the findElement action will be stop and the page will be refresh.

So I try to use multi-threading in Java to perform this:

- one thread is use to count the time out.
- and other thread (main thread) will use to execute the action.

The problem is: I can not interrupt the findElement action thread. 
These are the list of thread I'm seeing when try to execute my test:

- Thread: Attach Listener
- Thread: Finalize
- Thread: Signal Dispatcher
- Thread: Refresh TimeOut Thread
- Thread: Thread-6
- Thread: Forwarding findElements on session f7fea321-0acd-4df3-904d-52e32decb965 to remote
- Thread: Thread-7
- Thread: Thread-5

The Thread: main actually change to Thread: Forwarding findElements on session f7fea321-0acd-4df3-904d-52e32decb965 to remote. I will call this thread "findElement thread" for clarification in this question.

When I try to interrupt "findElement thread" the findElement action is still running without any interruption. I have try interrupt another thread (Thread: Thread-5) but it will remove the connection with current web-driver and test will be failed. I don't know if i did anything wrong is that the right thread to be interrupted ?

Thanks for reading this.
Any suggestion would be very much appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigate i found out that this is not possible:

when we use java to call web-driver to perform an selenium action that action will transfer to web-driver to perform and at this point we will not be able to manipulate this action any more let alone the thread that it use to perform this action, because from this point on web-driver control the execution not Java.

Answer (score 0):

A different way to achieve your goal is to simply use the FluentWait API of Selenium and initiate a page refresh every time it polls to find the requested element:

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
        return driver.findElement(...));
    }
});
```

If you have dynamically loaded elements on the page you should probably also wait for the page to be loaded before calling driver.findElement(...)